# How to change click option on Javascript to work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, button, click, accordion

I have found this code that works perfectly for what i need button that acts "as accordion" / open when click. Yet, the code doesn't work on mobile version.
Can you please help?

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
jQuery(function($){
$('.showme').click(function(){
$(this).closest('.elementor-section').next().slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass('opened');
});
$('.closebutton').click(function(){
$(this).closest('.elementor-section').prev().find('.showme').click();
});
});
});
</script>
<style>
.showme a , .showme i , .showme img, .closebutton a, .closebutton i, .closebutton img{
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: transform 0.34s ease;
transition : transform 0.34s ease;
}
.opened i , .opened img{
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you please provide some debugging ? or error message ?

Comment: when you click on the button, it doesn't open and show the content on mobile, but it does it on laptop (click seems to work but not on finger)

Comment: Any chance to get an answer?

Comment: can you try other browsers on mobile and see if it works

Comment: No it is not working, that's why I need help. I think the problem come that the .click doesn't know with touch point (like phone).